# WPF - Font Awesome icons not showing in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, font-awesome

I'm building WPF application and I want to use icons from Font Awesome. I have Font Awesome included in styles, and a font family specified in fields where I want to use it. The problem is icons are showing properly in the design window but change to crossed squares during runtime.

There is my Fonts XAML

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ArconRegular">pack://application;,,,/Fonts/#Arcon</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="ArconRounded">pack://application;,,,/Fonts/#Arcon Rounded-</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FASolid">pack://application;,,,/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid</FontFamily>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="BaseStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ArconRegular}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="BaseTextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ArconRegular}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>

    <system:String x:Key="FAMinimizeIcon">&#xf2d1;</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="FAMaximizeIcon">&#xf2d0;</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="FACloseIcon">&#xf00d;</system:String>
```

The Buttons XAML (I want to use icons on buttons)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WindowControlButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FASolid}"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundMainBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And finally MainWindow XAML (a part of it where i want to use them)

```
<!-- Window Buttons -->
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" Content="{StaticResource FAMinimizeIcon}" Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" Content="&#xf2d0;" Command="{Binding MaximizeCommand}"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource WindowCloseButton}" Content="&#xf00d;" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see, I tried specifying icon code in separate string and using StaticResource but nothing works.

Comment: Try adding ```x:Shared="False"``` to the resource declarations.  Here's the documentation for the Shared attribute: [x:Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute)

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work. What's funny, I used font awesome on my previous project and it worked just fine. I don't really know what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was missing `FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"` in the `ControlTemplate`

Comment: Took me 2 hours figuring this one out.. Thanks, exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had a same issue, i.e Showing ok in Design mode but no Runtime. For me it was because fontawesome was not included in the assembly.

Changed (in visual studio) the .otf file's Build Action to "Resource". You may want to check if the file is included in your assembly by decompiler.